# Convert React custom component with stylings into PDF and download file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, custom-component, react-to-pdf

As title says, I have to convert React component into PDF document and then be able to download it. Final PDF document should be consisted of 4 pages, where every page is one React component. These React components are very customized (including QR codes and so on). I tried `react-pdf/rendered` but problem is that their `Document` component accepts only predefined components from their library (`Page, Document, View, etc.`) and I can't create desired components with them. Also, take into account that I'm using Typescript so no all available libs from NPM can be used, because not all of them have TS support. Any help?

Comment: Do you need to allow your users to do this many times, or do you just need to do it once or a few times for yourself? If the latter than there are several options, and my go-to would be a puppeteer. See, e.g., here: https://blog.risingstack.com/pdf-from-html-node-js-puppeteer/

Comment: Maybe this [React Component to PDF tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-component-to-pdf) helps you and other people!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, what you need is to export a part of your UI or a Component to PDF, if it is what you are aiming you can try `html2canvas`: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

If it's not what you want please clarify.

Comment: wouldn't `html2canvas` create a rasterized version of the html ?